# Docker desktop stopping

Tags: docker

I am facing issue with Docker desktop.
Docker desktop version 4.20.0
Docker engine: 24.0.2
Macos: Ventura 13.4 M1 cjip

Dockerd panic:

> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.871257668Z][dockerd][I] panic: invalid freelist
> page: 0, page type is unknown<00>
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.871260793Z][dockerd][I]
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.871267251Z][dockerd][I] goroutine 1 [running,
> locked to thread]: [2023-06-01T12:08:48.872935418Z][dockerd][I]
> github.com/docker/docker/vendor/go.etcd.io/bbolt.(*freelist).read(0xaaaae7120ef3?,
> 0xffff5ef7b000) [2023-06-01T12:08:48.872946084Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/go.etcd.io/bbolt/freelist.go:267
> +0x1d8 [2023-06-01T12:08:48.872952793Z][dockerd][I] github.com/docker/docker/vendor/go.etcd.io/bbolt.(*DB).loadFreelist.func1()
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.872952959Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/go.etcd.io/bbolt/db.go:415
> +0xac [2023-06-01T12:08:48.873508584Z][dockerd][I] sync.(*Once).doSlow(0x400023d848?, 0xaaaae77efce0?)
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.873517334Z][dockerd][I]
> /usr/local/go/src/sync/once.go:74 +0x104
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.873522043Z][dockerd][I] sync.(*Once).Do(...)
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.873522418Z][dockerd][I]
> /usr/local/go/src/sync/once.go:65
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.873524418Z][dockerd][I]
> github.com/docker/docker/vendor/go.etcd.io/bbolt.(*DB).loadFreelist(0x400023d680?)
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.873524543Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/go.etcd.io/bbolt/db.go:408
> +0x48 [2023-06-01T12:08:48.873526626Z][dockerd][I] github.com/docker/docker/vendor/go.etcd.io/bbolt.Open({0x400102e9f0,
> 0x2a}, 0x0?, 0x0) [2023-06-01T12:08:48.873526793Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/go.etcd.io/bbolt/db.go:290
> +0x3a0 [2023-06-01T12:08:48.873822126Z][dockerd][I] github.com/docker/docker/builder/builder-next.newGraphDriverController({_,
> *}, {*, *}, {0x4000ba6ac8, {0x4000ef99b0, 0x18}, {0x40002265a0, 0x24}, {0x4000eb7470, ...}, ...})
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.873825501Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/builder/builder-next/controller.go:196
> +0x4b8 [2023-06-01T12:08:48.873831584Z][dockerd][I] github.com/docker/docker/builder/builder-next.newController({*, *},
> {*, *}, {0x4000ba6ac8, {0x4000ef99b0, 0x18}, {0x40002265a0, 0x24},
> {0x4000eb7470, ...}, ...})
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.873831793Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/builder/builder-next/controller.go:60
> +0x94 [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874771334Z][dockerd][I] github.com/docker/docker/builder/builder-next.New({*, _},
> {0x4000ba6ac8, {0x4000ef99b0, 0x18}, {0x40002265a0, 0x24},
> {0x4000eb7470, {0xaaaae7afa2a0, 0x40009b32b0}, ...}, ...})
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874782043Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/builder/builder-next/builder.go:113
> +0x114 [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874786459Z][dockerd][I] main.newRouterOptions({0xaaaae7af7248, 0x4000afc630}, 0x4000bab400,
> 0x4000abc000) [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874786626Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/cmd/dockerd/daemon.go:351 +0x60c
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874788584Z][dockerd][I]
> main.(*DaemonCli).start(0x4000bf6d40, 0x4000c4ab60)
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874788751Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/cmd/dockerd/daemon.go:265 +0xe08
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874790709Z][dockerd][I] main.runDaemon(...)
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874791001Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/cmd/dockerd/docker_unix.go:14
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874792834Z][dockerd][I]
> main.newDaemonCommand.func1(0x4000808300?, {0x4000c4abd0?, 0x7?,
> 0x7?}) [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874792959Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/cmd/dockerd/docker.go:39 +0xa8
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874795043Z][dockerd][I]
> github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x4000808300,
> {0x400004e090, 0x7, 0x7}) [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874945043Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:916
> +0x5c8 [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874947543Z][dockerd][I] github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x4000808300)
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874951793Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1044
> +0x35c [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874951959Z][dockerd][I] github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874963709Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:968
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874963876Z][dockerd][I] main.main()
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.874966168Z][dockerd][I]
> /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/cmd/dockerd/docker.go:109 +0x1a8
> [2023-06-01T12:08:48.883981959Z][dockerd][I] EOF

Tried to reinstall but didnt work.

Comment: This is really unclear, we have no idea what is happening if you just post an error like this. Please follow [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)